# Make 00:19:59 by jsvascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I try to show 20 minute by this format : (00:20:00) using setInterval and when it is done the format should be like this (00:00:00) ; but i can't.

```
<body onload = "onloadFunc();">
<span id="minute"></span> <span id="second"></span> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var interval;
function onloadFunc(){

    secondDown();
    interval = setInterval(secondDown, 1000);
}
 var countsec = 60;
 function secondDown(){
 document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = countsec;
 countsec--;
if(countsec == -1){
 minuteDown();
 interval = setInterval(minuteDown,60000);
 countsec = 60
}
}
var countmin = 20;
function minuteDown()
{
    document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = countmin;
    countmin--;
    if(countmin == -1)
    {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: I suggest setting your initial state either in the HTML or (more easily) from the `onloadFunc`. That state should be accessible from your JS as it currently is but also be represented in the HTML, which it isn't. Additionally, you should count seconds down from 59 rather than 60 (there's no 18:60, that's 19:00 -> same remark for your initial state, you should start at 0 seconds, 20min+60sec is 21:00)

Comment: Another problem you might miss : you're using two intervals (one counting down minutes, the other seconds) but you're storing both in the same `interval` variable which you use to clear the interval when you've reached the end of the timer. The problem is that this will only clear the `secondDown` timeout, and if you wait one more minute you'll see it decrease. I think it would be way easier to only use a single interval checking if it should decrease minute&reset seconds or just decrease seconds, but if you want to keep your two intervals you'll have to store them both in order to clear them.

Comment: Could you please show me the correct code? another problem is that after passing 120 seconds the number of minute will be decreased Twice , i mean the timer from 18.00 goes to 16.59 not 17.59

Comment: Yeah that makes sense : each time you reach 0 seconds you create a new `minuteDown` timer, but you never clear the previous one, so the minutes will decrease first by one, but then by 2, 3, etc. I'll see if I can find the time to write the code (I'm not very experienced with JS, and quite busy otherwise) but I'm sure if you try to rewrite your code with a single interval that runs every second and handles both minutes and seconds you'll find it quite easy to code yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a single interval makes everything easier :

```js
var seconds, minutes, interval;
function onloadFunc(){
    seconds=parseInt(document.getElementById("second").innerText);
    minutes=parseInt(document.getElementById("minute").innerText);
    interval = setInterval(tick, 1000);
}
function tick() {
  if (seconds > 0) {
   seconds--;
  } else { // seconds == 0
      if (minutes > 0) {
       minutes--;
        seconds=59; 
        document.getElementById("minute").innerText = minutes;
      } else { // minutes == 0 && seconds == 0 , let's stop the timer
       clearInterval(interval);
      }
  }
  document.getElementById("second").innerText = seconds < 10 ? "0"+ seconds : seconds; // seconds are always updated, minutes only when it matters
}
```

```html
<body onload = "onloadFunc();">
<span id="minute">20</span>:<span id="second">00</span>
</body>
```